# Interpreting predict_proba, multinomial Naive Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, multiclass-classification

I used `MultinomialNB()` from `scikit-learn`. Using `predict_proba`, how can I interpret these probabilites? My initial guess was: a probability of 0.8 means that the classifier is 80% certain that class X is the right class.

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110209/multiclass-classification-probabilities-and-calibration), but no answers were provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.
As you can read in documentation, predict_proba returns the probability of the samples for each class in the model. So, if we assume that you have 4 classes in your trained model and predict_proba returns [0.6, 0.2, 0.19, 0.01] (it's always sums up to 1) it is saying that your data is first class with 60% probability, second with 20% etc.

Documentation:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html

Comment: Okay thanks!
Do you happen to know what happens with the interpretation once the probabilities are calibrated? (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html)

Comment: Interpretation of probabilities are always the same, calibration is changing only their values.